# Swift method that returns 'Never'. How to mute warning?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I've got this simple code snippet, that describes a protocol and a protocol extension with a method that never returns (used to be `@noreturn` in Swift 2.x):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func foo() -> Never
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func foo() -> Never  {
        print("foobar")
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

It's in Swift 3 and compiled by Xcode 8.0 on El Capitan. It gives me a warning in line 6 that I don't understand and cannot get rid of:

`Test.playground:6:8: Will never be executed`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, I get same warning in a compiled project. The warning vanishes if you define the function in the extension only (but that changes the static/dynamic dispatch behaviour).

Comment: as matter of fact, there's a related [SR-2105](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2105) still opened

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Seems to be a bug. Something similar was reported a few hours ago: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2729

Comment: Still valid in Xcode 8.1 (8B62)